# How to move mailbox from one Exchange 2010 to another (different domain)?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010

I got 2 Exchange 2010 in different domain, say **Domain A** & **Domain B** (different server, different network segment).

I want to move the mailbox from Domain A to Domain B. What should I do?

p.s. emails going to move to domain B has been moved to a separated mailbox database.

Comment: All the mailboxes, or just one or two?

Comment: 3 mailbox databases containing 100, 50 & 20 mailboxes respectively. Planned to move the databases containing 50 & 20 mailboxes. The 100-mailbox database will leave in old server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the question is somewhat dated, but this might be of some use to others: as you have two exchange organizations, you would not be able to simply move the mailboxes across. I believe the only supported way would be to [export the mailboxes on the source server and import them on the destination server](http://www.msexchange.org/articles_tutorials/exchange-server-2010/management-administration/exporting-importing-mailboxes-exchange-server-2010.html).

Answer (score 0):

This question has ***quite*** different answers if the two servers are in the same Exchange organization or not. Please provide this info.

Comment: different Exchange organization.

Comment: @Massimo, Don't recall Microsoft was able to support 2 Exchange orgs in one domain. Yes for forest, but NO for domains.

Comment: @Vick: I was talking about the *opposite* scenario: two domains, same forest, same org.